# Project specific LDAP authorization for SVN

Tags: apache-2.4, openldap, svn

I am using Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 and SVN 1.8.8.

I have installed SVN server and created a number of repositories (one per client). For each team working for each client, I added configurations files in /etc/apache2/conf-available and use a2enconf. The files are of the format:

```
<Location /svn/Client1/>
  DAV svn
  SVNPATH /home/svn/Client1
  Options -Indexes
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Company SVN"
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=binduser,dc=company,dc=com"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "binduserpassword"
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.company.com:389/ou=users,dc=company,dc=com?cn?sub?(objectClass=posixAccount)"
  AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
  AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
  Require ldap-group cn=client1,dc=company,dc=com
</Location>
```

On my LDAP server, I created groupOfNames such as "client1", "client2" and added my team members to them. So far, so good. Everything works. If a team member is assigned to a client, I add him to that group and he gets access.

Now, I need to grant one specific user (who works for the client) access to not the whole repo, but a particular project within it.

I added his entry to LDAP then I tried adding a Location directive:

```
<Location /svn/Client1/Project17/>
  Require ldap-user cn=adam
</Location>
```

Didn't work. If I open `http://svn.company.com/svn/Client1/Project17/` in a browser, I get the Basic authentication popup where it accepts my own user/password, but not for the "adam" user. Apache log shows:

```
[Tue Jun 27 07:44:33.213571 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 29295] [client 121.153.248.253:65432] AH01631: user adam: authorization failure for "/svn/Client1/Project17/"
```

I set the LogLevel of Apache to debug. This shows that it is checking the group `cn=client1,dc=company,dc=com` and not finding the user there. This indicates that the second Location directive is not doing anything.

Yes, I restart apache2 after every change.

Comments?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with AllowOverride ? Something like AllowOverride AuthConfig ? see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/auth.html#theprerequisites

Comment: What I understand from the link you gave, is if any resource is protected using the configuration files then the directives may not be overridden by any .htaccess files within those directories unless there's a AllowOverride AuthConfig directive present.